# Grouping getters and setters by field in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When auto-formatting in IntelliJ, I get this:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
```

But I need not to have an blank line between the getter and setter of one field. Like this:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
```

Is it possible? At least in plugins?

Comment: may I ask why you need this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, all you have now is an option to keep getters and setters together in grouping rules, and a setting on how many blank lines around a method there should be

Comment: It's not possible with the default formatter. You can check if any third-party formatter supports it and use it instead, such as [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter).